# C++ function providing multiple values: reference parameters, or tuple?

Tags: c++, c++17

For decades I've been making functions that provide multiple values do so by parameter list:

```
void initialize (World& world, Monster& monster, Player& player)
{
   world.load("worldFile.txt");
   monster.load ("monsterFile.txt"); monster.setPos (100,0,0);
   player.setPos (0,0,0);
}
```

C++17, of course, provides tuples, but this looks inefficient:

```
std::tuple<World, Monster, Player> initialize ()
{
   World world; Monster monster; Player player; //do loading etc.;
   return {world, monster, player};
}
```

But this should be OK (I think):

```
std::tuple<double, std::string> makeSomething ()
{
    return {5.0, "someString"s};
}
```

At what point does the copy overhead get high enough that it's wiser to use reference parameters than a tuple? or is there a way to make the `auto initialize` version efficient?

Comment: I don't think returning `[...]` is well formed.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Right you are.

Comment: The second and third snippets should return `std::make_tuple(world, monster, player)` instead, right? Edit: the author might be referring to [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) syntax, which is not valid here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice discussion on parameters and return values in the [core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-conventional).

> F.20: For “out” output values, prefer return values to output parameters

The only reason to use references are big objects. By the guidelines, "big" means custom allocations or copies of more 1KB contiguous memory.

Comment: Very comprehensive! Can you clarify what "in and retain copy" means in that link?

Comment: A parameter can either be used directly (e.g. for calculating a return value) or stored for later use. The latter requires a copy (=retain). In this case you can optimize the way of passing the argument by providing an additional move-overload. Some authors (Scott Meyers in _Effective Modern C++_) argue that providing a single copy-move function is better than providing two functions (const-ref + move).

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the objects in order to avoid copies:

```
std::tuple<World, Monster, Player> initialize ()
{
    // ...
    return {std::move(world), std::move(monster), std::move(player)};
}
```

The types must be movable. If they're not, you still get copies.

Comment: This might be suboptimal. See [F48 don't return std::move local](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f48-dont-return-stdmovelocal)

Comment: @JorgeBellon RVO/NRVO doesn't apply here. The tuple itself is RVO'ed, but the contents of the tuple (the `world`, `monster` and `player` objects) are not.

Comment: So what if `World` (for example) is expensive to move (think of `std::array<int,LARGE_N>`)? Wouldn't it make more sense to construct the elements in the tuple directly using something like `std::piecewise_construct`?